# jquery cambiar el atributo src

Tags: jquery, atributos

Me han pedido hacer un reproductor de streaming y tengo un dropDownList, pero, al elegirlo no se como cambiar el atributo src de este pedazo de codigo:

```
 <div class="player">
 <div class="videoBox" style="padding: 0; position: relative;">
<a id="TempPlayBtn" href="javascript:;" onClick="demoplayer.play(); $('#TempPlayBtn').remove();" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: 50px; height: 50px; z-index: 9999;"></a>
 <video id="demo-player" controls playsinline class="cld-video-player" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px" height="500">
 <source src="https://ss3.domint.net:3114/t11_str/telesistema/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
```

He estado buscando en la web console a donde tengo que referirme para poder cambiar el valor del src cuando elija cualquier valor del dropDownList.

Si fuera un iframe simplemente seria un jquery asi:

```
 $('#canal').clic(function({
      if($(#canal).val() == 2){
            $('#idIframe').atrr(src,'nuevo source')
}
});
```

Pero no he podido dar con lo que necesito para cambiar el src, muchas gracias por su ayuda

Este es mi codigo

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Telesistema</title>




<!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<meta property="og:url" content="http://telesistema11.com.do/en-directo" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="En Vivo" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Telesistema" />
<meta property="og:image" content="}" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/cloudinary-video-player/dist/cld-video-player.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <meta property="fb:app_id" content="860356994135936" />

  <script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>


 </head>
 <body>

<div class="directo-layout">


<div class="player">
<div class="videoBox" style="padding: 0; position: relative;">
<a id="TempPlayBtn" href="javascript:;" onClick="demoplayer.play(); $('#TempPlayBtn').remove();" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: 50px; height: 50px; z-index: 9999;"></a>
 <video id="demo-player" controls playsinline class="cld-video-player" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px" height="500">

 <source  src="https://ss3.domint.net:3114/t11_str/telesistema/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />



  </video>
  </div>


  </div>
  </div>

  <select id="canal">
<option value="seleccion" selected>Seleccionar Canal</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="37">37</option>
 </select> 


  </div>
  <hr>




 </div>
 </div>

 </div>


 </div>



   <script src="https://telesistema11.com.do/themes/telesistemas/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://telesistema11.com.do/themes/telesistemas/assets/js/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://telesistema11.com.do/themes/telesistemas/assets/js/dropdown.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       stream = false;
       num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) + 1);

       /* ---------------------------------------- */
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/streaming",
           data: "num=" + num,
           success: function (datos) {
               stream = datos;

               if (stream === "false") {
                   $("#CurrentVideo").html('<div id="avisostream" style="padding:7em 0; text-align:center; height:485px;"><span style="font-size: 4em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span><br /><br /><strong>Sin transmision por internet.</strong><br />En estos momentos no estamos transmitiendo.</div>');
                   $("a.live").hide();
               }
           }
       });  

   });

   $("#canal").click(function() {
    if ($("#canal").val() == 21) {
      $("#demo-player.source").val()=
        "http://d16zdyqofyr6h0.cloudfront.net/player_do_canal21.html";

        location.reload();


    }
    if ($("#canal").val() == 7) {
      $("#video").attr(
        "src",
        "http://d16zdyqofyr6h0.cloudfront.net/player_do_antena_latina.html"
      );
    }
    if ($("#canal").val() == 5) {
      $("#video").attr(
        "src",
        "https://www.grupotelemicro.com/livestream/tablalive"
      );
    }
    if ($("#canal").val() == 4) {
      $("#video").attr(
        "src",
        "https://livestream.com/accounts/27035275/events/8371710/player?"
      );
    }
    if ($("#canal").val() == 2) {
      $("#video").attr(
        "src",
        "https://ss1.domint.net:3126/ta2_str/teleantillas/playlist.m3u8"
      );
    }
    if ($("#canal").val() == 11) {
      $("#video").attr("src", "http://telesistema11.com.do/en-directo");
    }
    if ($("#canal").val() == 9) {
      $("#video").attr(
        "src",
        "https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x6tt2y8"
      );
    }
    if ($("#canal").val() == 13) {
      $("#video").attr(
        "src",
        "https://livestream.com/accounts/27035275/events/8371710/player?"
      );
    }
    if ($("#canal").val() == 15) {
      $("#video").attr(
        "src",
        "https://telemicro.com.do/web/digital-15-en-vivo/"
      );
    }
    if ($("#canal").val() == 37) {
      $("#video").attr(
        "src",
        "https://cdn.com.do/b8b9308a-44ea-4939-a512-0038bfb2578b"
      );
    }
    if ($("#canal").val() == 25) {
      $("#video").attr(
        "src",
        "http://dominicanplayers.com/video-player/265/0/0"
      );
    }
  });




    </script>
```

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var demoplayer;



$(document).ready(function(){
    // Cloudinary Video
    var cld = cloudinary.Cloudinary.new({
        cloud_name: "telesistema-cloud",
        secure: true
    });
       demoplayer = cld.videoPlayer('demo-player', {
        ads: {
            //adTagUrl: "https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-video-pub-7896857778453643&slotname=1426185775&ad_type=video_text_image&description_url=http%3A%2F%2Ftelesistema11.com.do&videoad_start_delay=0&vpmute=0&vpa=0", 
            locale:"es",
            adLabel:"Tu video comenzará en"
        }
    });
});
```

muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Dado que es un `select`, puedes hacer algo así:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#sel-video').on('change', function() {
    var srcVideo = $(this).val();
      $('#demo-player').attr('src', srcVideo);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel-video">
  <option value="https://ss3.domint.net:3114/t11_str/telesistema/playlist.m3u8" selected=true>--Escoja un vídeo--</option>
  <option value="https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/apis/video-audio/finished/video/sintel-short.mp4">Mountain</option>
  <option value="https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/video-and-audio-content/rabbit320.mp4">Rabbit</option>
</select>


<video id="demo-player" controls playsinline class="cld-video-player" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px" height="500">
 <source src="https://ss3.domint.net:3114/t11_str/telesistema/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
```

Aquí se escuchan los cambios del `select` y se usa el `value` del mismo para poner la URL del vídeo. Cuando el `select` cambia, se setea a `src` el video correspondiente.

En la primera opción he puesto el vídeo que viene en el contenedor `video` (como si fuera por defecto), para que si se vuelve a esa opción, se ponga de nuevo ese vídeo en el contenedor. Esto es útil por ejemplo si de entrada se quiere mostrar un vídeo de bienvenida.

Comment: Aun asi no logro hacer que tome el valor del elemento elegido, debe ser por k tengo esto: <link href="https://unpkg.com/cloudinary-video-player/dist/cld-video-player.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <meta property="fb:app_id" content="860356994135936" />. Creo que investigare mas sobre este reproductor, se que debe de existir alguna forma, muchas gracias por la ayuda, aprendi algo nuevo